# Fetching and binding data incrementally in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, asynchronous, fetch

In one of the pages in my ASP.NET application, I need to query data from a table having large amount of data. I want to fetch the data asynchronously and bind it incrementally to my page.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: [Implement the AJAX Incremental Page Display Pattern](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/aspnet-ajax/how-do-i-implement-the-ajax-incremental-page-display-pattern)

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would be nice you could add a few code samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used something similar to incremental page display pattern but with SignalR to achieve it. Because, SignalR's calls are asynchronous and I thought that it is a proper fit to my scenario.